# \floatfoot of floatrow package causing unexpected color changes

Tags: floats, color, footnotes, floatrow

I use `floatrow` to format my floats, and noticed some unexpected behaviour. In the `\InsertTable` command I created, if the final, optional `[]` argument is present, which is supposed be for optional table footnotes, the following text color in the next paragraph is changed to black (when it should be white). I've traced this down to the `\floatfoot` commmand. Perhaps this is a little bug? It appears on CTAN, this package hasn't been updated since 2009, maybe I should consider a different package to assist with my floats?

[image: With [Footnote] enabled]
[image: With [Footnote] commented out]

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{xparse}

\usepackage{floatrow}

\NewDocumentCommand{\DoIfnotEmpty}{m m O{}}{\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{#3}{#2}}

\NewDocumentCommand{\InsertTable}{ s O{htbp} D<>{} m m O{#5} m O{} }{%
    \begin{table}[#2]% htbp! settings
        #3% pre-amble
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}{% if star, use the wide format
            \captionsetup{labelformat=default}\floatsetup{margins=raggedright}%
            \RawCaption{\caption[#6]{#5}}#7% caption outside ttbabbox, and freed from float width
            \ttabbox{}{#4\DoIfnotEmpty{#8}{\vspace{1ex}\floatfoot*{#8}}}% if no star then use hanging
        }{% if not, use the hanging style
            \ttabbox{\caption[#6]{#5}#7}{#4\DoIfnotEmpty{#8}{\vspace{1ex}\floatfoot*{#8}}}%  if floatfoot removed, expected behaviour
        }%
    \end{table}%
}

\pagecolor[rgb]{0.2,0.2,0.25}
\color[rgb]{0.98,0.98,0.93}

\begin{document}

\section{Section}

hello

\InsertTable[htbp]%
{A placeholder for a table}%
{Caption}%
{\label{t.label}}%
[Footnote]% complied with this here, or commented out. Different colors on next paragraph

\section{Section}

This part is black (when white is expected) if the table above has a footnote (final argument present).
It appears that floatfoot* causes this.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

floatrow doesn't guard a \normalcolor and so it resets the color after the table. You could try this

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\FB@putfoots{%
  \ifvoid\flrow@foot\else\FR@ifFOOT
    {\vskip\floatfootskip\color@begingroup\normalcolor
    \unvbox\flrow@foot\@@par\color@endgroup}\relax
  \fi} 
\makeatother
```